# Regular expression for function(s) in create table statement

Tags: mysql, regex

I am struggling in writing regular expression for getting function in create table statement.
For example create table statement can be-

```
CREATE TABLE `table1` (                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
      `a` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,                                                                                                                                                                                                          
      `b` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
      `c` int(11) AS (((a mod 10)mod 10)) VIRTUAL,                                                                                                                                                                                                  
      `d` varchar(5) AS (left(b,5)) PERSISTENT,                                                                                                                                                                                                     
      KEY `a` (`a`)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

I want to get functions such as (((a mod 10)mod 10)) and  (left(b,5)) which can be defined only for VIRTUAL/PERSISTENT columns. This function can be any valid expression in MySQL. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: People that pre-req a specific method (like regexes) often shut out a large number of possible solutions. Unless regex is an absolute requirement, you should instead ask "how do I detect functions in a create table statatement?".

Comment: It is not possible with Show full fields...or There is no information about these functions in INFORMATION_SCHEMA also. So I guess regex is the only option I have.

Comment: I have asked It here BTW-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27687421/how-to-get-functions-for-virtual-persistent-column

Comment: In which programming language do you want to create your tool?

Answer (score 0):

You can use view.

Or you can create trigger for insert and update to database. On each operation trigger will calculate values for columns.

Comment: I don't want to get values of columns. I want function in column definition. i.e. I want to get (((a mod 10)mod 10)) as result.

Comment: @AbhishekPandey You need function for columns type? What is your use case?

Comment: I want to create alter table GUI tool. User can alter the expression in my GUI tool and this tool will generate query accordingly.